# Merge two table in ms-access 2010 with auto rename repeated fields

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to merge two tables but my problem is that I want the code recognize future entries. I want it has the ability to sort new sample and rename the field as (_1,_2,… and continue). These are my tables:

```
Table1    
    ID  F_Name  L_Name  Addr    Phone
    1   A1      A2      A3      A4
    2   B1      B2      B3      B4
    3   C1      C2      C3      C4
```

And

```
Table2
ID  Date    Smpl    Color
1   D1      D2      D3
2   E1      E2      E3
1   F1      F2      F3
1   G1      G2      G3
3   H1      H2      H3
2   I1      I2      I3
```

And I want the merged table to look like this:

```
Results:
ID  F_Name  L_Name  Addr    Phone   Date_1  Smpl_1  Color_1 Date_2  Smpl_2  Color_2 Date_3  Smpl_3  Color_3
1   A1      A2      A3      A4      D1      D2      D3      F1      F2      F3      G1      G2      G3
2   B1      B2      B3      B4      E1      E2      E3      I1      I2      I3          
3   C1      C2      C3      C4      H1      H2      H3
```

I am confused and I cannot get correct result. Could you please help me in query code?
I want data from table 2 to be added and renamed in old to new order.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this a one time merge, or do you want to make it a routine that can be called several times?

Comment: I want to use it for several times not just one time. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter, because each time this is run, it will re-create table 3 will all the info wanted. It's not the most elegant solution, but it's probably the easiest for a beginner.

Comment: Are you able to write a query to get the max possible count from table 1? Hint: You'll need a nested query or stacked queries, first getting the count of each group, then getting the max count.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easiest to use VBA. I'll give you the step by step directions, but you'll have to lookup the commands and syntax for each step.

---

First determine the max possible count of any ID from table 2. In your sample, it's 3 (from ID #1). We'll call it N.

Now you'll execute a "DROP TABLE" query. We'll call it table 3.

Then you'll execute a "CREATE TABLE" query and base your field count using N. We'll call it table 3.

And then reset the flags in table 2 using an UPDATE query.

Execute an append query using from table 1 to table 3.

Loop the next 2 steps N times.

Execute an update query linking tables 2 & 3 via the ID field, this query will use the **first** grouping option and filtering out any records based on a set flag field in table 2. This will update the Date_N / Smpl_N / Color_N fields in table 3.
Execute another update with the same criteria as above but set the flag in table 2.

---

What you are doing here is taking the first record of each person that isn't flagged and using that info to update your records. You are then flagging those records you just used to update with so that on the next pass they are skipped.

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner and trying to figure out your recommendation. My problem is that people in table 1 will be updating and new persons may add to the list. I want a dynamic query which update the data.